# VBA Code to copy multiple files into single specified excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I am starting to learn VB coding (been 2 days). So far so good. But I need help on copying multiple files from a folder into a single specified sheet(or active sheet). I looked up online and and based on that I was able to get it working. The problem is after the first file is copied, the next file gets copied to rows below the first file data. I want to change the code past in next column rather than last row. Each file is 3 column, so basically File1 data will be first 3 columns, then file 2 will be column 4-6 and so on. This means the rows will be same for each data. I tried modifying the code to achieve this but so far no luck...

```
Sub CombineMultipleFiles()
' Path - modify as needed but keep trailing backslash
  Const sPath = "C:\My_stuff\Test\"
  Dim sFile As String
  Dim wbkSource As Workbook
  Dim wSource As Worksheet
  Dim wTarget As Worksheet
  Dim lRows As Long
  Dim lMaxSourceRow As Long
  Dim lMaxTargetRow As Long
Dim lMaxTargetColumn As Long
  'Dim blnNoHeader As Boolean

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  'lMaxTargetRow = 0
  Set wTarget = ActiveSheet
  lRows = wTarget.Rows.Count
  sFile = Dir(sPath & "*.s1p*")
  Do While Not sFile = ""
    Set wbkSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sPath & sFile, AddToMRU:=False)
    For Each wSource In wbkSource.Worksheets
    lMaxSourceRow = wSource.Cells(lRows, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lMaxTargetRow = wTarget.Cells(lRows, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    wSource.Range("1:" & lMaxSourceRow).Copy _
      Destination:=wTarget.Cells(lMaxTargetRow + 1, 1)
      Next
    wbkSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
    sFile = Dir
    'MsgBox lMaxTargetRow
  Loop


  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Very good! You are nearly there. The fault is in this line of your code.

```
Destination:=wTarget.Cells(lMaxTargetRow + 1, 1)
```

The lMaxTargetRow is the just reset last row. This is responsible for writing in the last row + 1. Fact is, I suspect that you want to write to the first or second row every time, just another column.

The column specified for the destination is always 1 (it is the last 1 before the closing parenthesis). Actually, you set up the variable lMaxTargetColumn perhaps for this purpose. However, I wouldn't check for the last column in each loop. Instead, I would set `lTargetColumn = 1` before starting the loop and then `lTargetColumn = lTargetColumn + 3` after each file was copied, unless you explicitly want to allow the imported files to have a variable column count, in which I would consider the Columns.Count property still as more reliable than looking for a blank space in any particular row of which you don't really know where it will be.

Anyway, if you change the above line of code to

```
Destination:=wTarget.Cells(1, lTargetColumn)
```

and add the appropriate management for `lTargetColumn` your code should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In order to paste the data copied correctly to the first empty column in `wTarget`, you need to find the first empty column.

You can achieve this by using the `Find` function.

```
Dim LastCell As Range

Do While Not sFile = ""
    Set wbkSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sPath & sFile, AddToMRU:=False)
    For Each wSource In wbkSource.Worksheets

        ' ===== add the Find code below inside your loop to find the last occupied column =====
        ' use Find to get the most updated last cell with data in wTarget sheet
        Set LastCell = wTarget.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=wTarget.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

        If Not LastCell Is Nothing Then ' <-- if Find was successful
            lMaxTargetColumn = LastCell.Column
        Else ' <-- sheets is empty
            lMaxTargetColumn = 1
        End If
        Set LastCell = Nothing

        ' ==== when pasting use the logic below ====
        ' your copy line ....
        Destination:=wTarget.Cells(1, lMaxTargetColumn + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CombineMultipleFiles()
' Path - modify as needed but keep trailing backslash
  Const sPath = "C:\My_stuff"
  Dim sFile As String
  Dim wbkSource As Workbook
  Dim wSource As Worksheet
  Dim wTarget As Worksheet
  Dim lRows As Long
  Dim lMaxSourceRow As Long
  Dim lMaxTargetRow As Long
Dim lMaxTargetColumn As Long
Dim lTargetColumn   As Long
  'Dim blnNoHeader As Boolean

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  'lMaxTargetRow = 0
  Set wTarget = ActiveSheet
  lRows = wTarget.Rows.Count
  sFile = Dir(sPath & "*.s1p*")
 lTargetColumn = 1
  Do While Not sFile = ""
    Set wbkSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sPath & sFile, AddToMRU:=False)
    For Each wSource In wbkSource.Worksheets
    lMaxSourceRow = wSource.Cells(lRows, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'MsgBox lMaxSourceRow
    'lMaxTargetRow = wTarget.Cells(lRows, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    wSource.Range("A:C").Copy _
    Destination:=wTarget.Cells(1, lTargetColumn)
      lTargetColumn = lTargetColumn + 3
      Next
    wbkSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
    sFile = Dir
    'MsgBox lMaxTargetRow
    'MsgBox "Done!"
  Loop


  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```